# How to access attribute from list field

Tags: python, mongodb, flask, mongoengine, wtforms

I am using mongodb and flask.
I have the following model:

```
class Post(db.Document):
    properties = db.ListField(db.EmbeddedDocumentField('Properties'))


class Properties(db.EmbeddedDocument):
    title = db.StringField(max_length=255, required=True)
    types = db.StringField(max_length=255, required=True)
    location_name = db.StringField(max_length=255, required=True)
    url = db.StringField(max_length=255, required=True)
    feed_url = db.StringField(max_length=255, required=True)
    content_url = db.StringField(max_length=255, required=True)
    date_added = db.StringField(max_length=255, required=True)
    date_crawled = db.StringField(max_length=255, required=True)
```

When i do `Post.properties` i get returned a list field.
I was wondering if anyone knew how to access the url attribute in the properties class.
Preferably i want to get the listfield where properties.url is equal for example "abc"

I have tried `Post.properties.url` and i get the following error

```
AttributeError: 'ListField' object has no attribute 'url'
```

Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

`Post.properties` has `ListField` type. So for `Post` instance `properties` has `list` type.

At first you must get `Post` instance (not class):

```
post_1 = Post.objects.first()  # get first from database
post_2 = Post().save()  # create and save
```

With `Post` instance you can get propery by index:

```
post = Post.objects.first()
print post.properties[0].url if post.properties else None
```

But better iterate for properties:

```
post = Post.objects.first()
for property in post.properties:
    print property.url
```

Also look to [mongoengine tutorial](https://mongoengine-odm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorial.html) and [user guide](https://mongoengine-odm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/guide/index.html).

Comment: Thanks to get all objects from the database do i just do Post.objects. I can seem to find where all these methods i can call are in the documentation.